# Help with FeedMe JSON

Tags: json, plugin-feedme, table-field

I am trying to insert records into the same entry using FeedMe with Matrix and Table for one of the fields.  My table field is a plain text.  So I have one programLevel, one program and a field that collects many text entry lists in a Table field.  No matter what I do, depending on the structure of the JSON.  I either overwrite the record already there or it gets 2 entries into the Matrix field but combines all the plain text entries into the Table field (code below).  Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Basically I end up with 2 Matrix entries but a combined Table field called Lists.  Basically, Test text 1, Test text 2, Test text 3, etc in the Table field for both Matrix records in the entry. Is there a proper way to get this formatted correctly please?

```
[
    {
        "title":"Test Entry",
        "programs": [
            {
                "programLevel":"Alpha",
                "program":"Vector1",
                "listItems": [
                    "Test text 1",
                    "Test text 2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "programLevel":"Beta",
                "program":"Vector1",
                "listItems": [
                    "Test text 3",
                    "Test text 4"
                ]
            }  
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I think this may be a bug in the plugin.  Using Craft 3.0.2.

Comment: Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Verbb for fixing this up. The answer can be found here.

https://github.com/verbb/feed-me/issues/298